# Uncompress a GZIP string in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decompress a gzipped data in a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270268/how-to-decompress-a-gzipped-data-in-a-byte-array)

I have a Gzip'd byte array and I simply want to uncompress it and print the output. It's something like this:

```
byte[] gzip = getGZIPByteArray();

/* Code do uncompress the GZIP */

System.out.print(uncompressedGZIP);
```

Can anybody help me with the code in the middle?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
// With 'gzip' being the compressed buffer
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream bytein = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(gzip);
java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream gzin = new java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream(bytein);
java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream byteout = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();

int res = 0;
byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
while (res >= 0) {
    res = gzin.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
    if (res > 0) {
        byteout.write(buf, 0, res);
    }
}
byte uncompressed[] = byteout.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 14):

The below method may give you a start :-

```
    public static byte[] decompress(byte[] contentBytes){
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try{
            IOUtils.copy(new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(contentBytes)), out);
        } catch(IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
```

Ensure that you have the below in your classpath and `import` them in your code.

```
import java.util.zip.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
```

Comment: This depends on apache commons IO api, which is not part of a standard Java distribution.

Comment: maybe you can add the compress function as well ?