# Decompressing a byte[] using GzipInputStream

Tags: java, compression, gzip

I have a class that compresses and decompresses a byte array;

```
public class Compressor
{
    public static byte[] compress(final byte[] input) throws IOException
    {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                GZIPOutputStream gzipper = new GZIPOutputStream(bout))
        {
            gzipper.write(input, 0, input.length);
            gzipper.close();

            return bout.toByteArray();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] decompress(final byte[] input) throws IOException
    {
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);
                GZIPInputStream gzipper = new GZIPInputStream(bin))
        {
            // Not sure where to go here
        }
    }
}
```

How do I decompress the input and return a byte array?

**Note:** I don't want to do any conversion to strings because of character encoding issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your missing code will be something like

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int len;
while ((len = gzipper.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}

gzipper.close();
out.close();
return out.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Would the read method pad the data if it doesn't have bytes to fill up the 1024? or would I get only the exact data of the same size back?

Comment: it's just a buffer. if the amount of bytes read (len) < buffer, then it will only read from 0 to len.

Comment: the important thing here is that, using a buffer, you won't have any risk to run out of memory while copying data from one stream to another.

Comment: What happens when the buffer is filled beyond 1024 bytes?

Comment: @Snap `gzipper.read(buffer)` guarantees it won't. The buffer array is filled, then the loop continues, and overwrites the previous content, starting at the beginning of the array