# How to receive zipped json data from RabbitMQ in scala

Tags: scala, rabbitmq

Im using below scala code to receive messages from rabbitmq.

```
 import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel
    import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection
    import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory
    import com.rabbitmq.client.ConsumerCancelledException
    import com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer
        

   val rabbitMQconnection = getRabbitMQConnection
    val channel = rabbitMQconnection.createChannel()
    val args = Map[String, AnyRef]("x-message-ttl" -> Long.box(40000))
                                       
         channel.queueDeclare("test",true,false,false,args )
          val consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel)
             channel.basicConsume("test",true,consumer)
           var message: String = null
         val delivery = consumer.nextDelivery()
         message= new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
         println("at consumer : " +message)
```

My input data from RabbitMq is zipped Json data. When I use the above code, Im unable to unzip the data. Could someone please let me know how to read zipped json data.

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't look like Spark Streaming code. Why are these tags included?

Comment: You should start with `val body = delivery.getBody()`, then pass this on to some unzip method. From which, you parse it with json library... `new String` assumes the data is UTF8 encoded plaintext, not compressed

Comment: Im doing this in spark and I have pasted on a part of the code. I am using spark streaming context.  The data is compressed. Could you please let me know how to handle this. I have done the similar thing in python using Pika. df = gzip.decompress(body). Unable to do the same in scala

Comment: Even in Python, that has nothing to do with Spark. You're calling a builtin gzip module function. For Scala, you'll need to find a similar library. Also, Gzip and zip are not the same

Comment: Since you can use Java code with Scala, for Gzip specifically, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/23606047/2308683 And similar answer would apply to using `ZipInputStream` instead.. From the decompressed bytes, you should be able to pass them on to a string constructor or JSON parser (Jackson accepts byte arrays, for example)

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you . I will try this.

Comment: @oneCricketeer. Could you please help with the below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70750017/empty-rdd-while-consuming-messages-from-rabbitmq-in-sparks-scala

Comment: Sorry, never used RabbitMQ with Spark.