# When are files "splittable"?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hdfs, file-format

When I'm using spark, I sometimes run into one huge file in a **HIVE** table, and I sometimes am trying to process many smaller files in a HIVE table.

I understand that when tuning spark jobs, how it works depends on whether or not the files are **splittable**. In [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/) page from cloudera, it says that we should be aware of whether or not the files are splittable:

> ...For example, if your data arrives in a few large unsplittable files...

1. How do I know if my file is splittable?
2. How do I know the number of partitions to use if the file is splittable ?
3. Is it better to err on the side of more partitions if I'm trying to write a piece of code that will work on any HIVE table, i.e. either of the two cases described above?

Answer (score 10):

Considering Spark accepts Hadoop input files, have a look at below image.

Only `bzip2` formatted files are splitable and other formats like `zlib, gzip, LZO, LZ4 and Snappy` formats are not splitable.

Regarding your query on partition, partition does not depend on file format you are going to use. It depends on content in the file - Values of partitioned column like date etc.

[image]

**EDIT 1:**
Have a look at this [SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402737/how-to-read-gz-files-in-spark-using-wholetextfiles) question and this [working code](https://github.com/yhemanth/spark-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dsinpractice/spark/samples/core/WholeTextFiles.java) on Spark reading zip file.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> fileNameContentsRDD = javaSparkContext.wholeTextFiles(args[0]);
        JavaRDD<String> lineCounts = fileNameContentsRDD.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(Tuple2<String, String> fileNameContent) throws Exception {
                String content = fileNameContent._2();
                int numLines = content.split("[\r\n]+").length;
                return fileNameContent._1() + ":  " + numLines;
            }
        });
        List<String> output = lineCounts.collect();
```

**EDIT 2:**

LZO files can be splittable.

> LZO files can be split as long as the splits occur on block boundaries

Refer to this [article](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/11/hadoop-at-twitter-part-1-splittable-lzo-compression/) for more details.

Comment: So, if the default hadoop files aren't `splittable`, then how does `sc.textFile(<name-of-file>)` still create an RDD of lines on hdfs files?  Or does it not?  How do I determine my file format?

Comment: Unsplitable does not mean that file is not going to be processed. It meant that data locality has been lost. If a 1 GB compressed unsplitable file has been stored in 8 blocks of 8 different nodes, only one mapper is created to process complete unsplitable file.

Comment: yeah, I know that the file will still get processed.  But, in _spark_, can an RDD still split the file up line-by-line and process it, or will it process it all as one?  Essentially how does the word `splittable` affect the way spark processes the file?

Comment: Splitable files allow processing to be distributed over multiple worker nodes. For non-splitable, I have updated the answer.

Comment: I'm not so hot on Java, so I'm slowly understanding that SE question you posted a link to.  But, in [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/) link, it suggests `repartition`ing  an RDD of un-splittable files.  So, you must be saying that the only the initial RDD is affected by the `non-splitability`.  After that, the RDD can be `repartition`ed.  Correct?

Comment: It is wrong that LZO files are not splittable. They are. You just have to index them. See hadoop-lzo project.

Comment: Snappy is splittable as long as it's applied after containerization