# Loading large CSV files in Databricks (Pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I need to load a CSV file that has a size of 500GB.

```
spark.read.csv("file.csv.gz")
```

takes hours. Is there a solution to speed that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have gzipped files, then it's expected, as such gzip files [aren't splittable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208051/when-are-files-splittable), and are handled with a single core. You have a choice of:

- decompress file, so it will be simple CSV file - then it will be splittable and could be processed in parallel
- try to use this [custom code](https://github.com/nielsbasjes/splittablegzip), but I'm not sure that it will work on Databricks without changes.