# Effective way to decompress or unzip the .gz file in java which contains number of json files in it? or list out all the files in same directory?

Tags: java, file-io, gzip

I have a .gz file like **sample_ddmmyy_hhmm.gz**, which contains number of JSON file as mentioned below:

```
1.sample1_ddmmyy_hhmm.json
2.sample2_ddmmyy_hhmm.json
3.sample3_ddmmyy_hhmm.json
```

I am able to read all the file contents from the .gz file, but I need individual JSON files to list out and corresponding JSON file data. I am using JDK version 1.6.

How can we uncompress the `sample_ddmmyy_hhmm.gz` file and list out the files in it, using Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decompress a gzipped data in a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270268/how-to-decompress-a-gzipped-data-in-a-byte-array)

Comment: Show us some of your code. Did you do an internet search ?